# Is there any valid reason there're no parent selectors in CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors

While there exist selectors to select items preceded (`#hlinks+#hsearch`) or owned (`#topbar>#hlinks`) by other items, there's **no way** to do the opposite.

For example there isn't something like

```
li:has(ul){ }
```

To detect list items that have other lists within them. Wouldn't that be convenient?

AFAIK, the feature is not even in the plans for CSS, so my question is: *why is this so*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is generally called a "parent selector"; as you say, they don't exist in CSS, though they could be useful.

There's an [interesting discussion here](http://css-tricks.com/parent-selectors-in-css/); the summary is that they would have a large negative effect on performance and would allow people to make mistakes with large consequences.  People who understand these things seem to think that these issues can be overcome, but there hasn't yet been sufficient demand for someone to actually do it.

Comment: > these issues can be overcome. Yes, but it's such a frequent need and it's always a pain in the ass to implement properly. Thanks for the answers to all, title edited for future-comers.

Comment: The impetus for adding this could come either from a standards body such as W3C, or from a browser maker such as Microsoft, Google, Mozilla, or Apple.  Some changes happen because one browser starts to support them, and then other browsers join in.  However, all of the browser makers are pretty focused on speed, so if performance really is a problem, that's going to make them wary.

Answer (score 3):

You're referring to the concept of a "parent" selector - selecting the parent element under a particular condition.  You're correct about this feature not being present in CSS (not event CSS3) - to my knowledge, it not possible at the moment to the way the DOM is parsed by CSS.  However, this feature is available using jQuery and the [`:parent`](http://api.jquery.com/parent-selector/) selector or the [`:has`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) selector, which it seems you may be familiar with already.

EDIT: For a tremendous amount of detail on the idea of a parent selector, see http://shauninman.com/archive/2008/05/05/css_qualified_selectors.

Answer (score -4):

This is standard in CSS since...uh.... the beginning of CSS.

It's just a space:

`li ul` means `any ul that is inside li`

Comment: I think he wants to target the `li` that has a `ul` child, not the `ul` itself.

Comment: I read the OP as wanting a selector for the li, which triggers only if it has a ul in it.

Answer (score -4):

If you want to do that just do:

```
ul li ul li {

}
```

So now you are searching for any list-item that has an unordered-list inside of it with a list item.

Comment: But this will find the list item at the bottom -- the poster wants to find the ul item at the top (if it contains a list inside).

Comment: @JacobM i am not sure what you mean

Comment: Your selector will allow the poster to style an `li` tag if it is within a list contained by another list.  But the poster wants to style the parent `li` tag (the li that is the second item in your list, not the fourth item), but only when that li contains another list.  Current selectors always target the last element described, but the poster wants to target the parent element.